# Best value for money on aero wheels

Tags: product-rec, wheels, parts

I cycle to work three times a week over a distance of 13 miles in both directions. I do approximately 20mph most of the way there and back and I am looking for ways to speed up the commute.

Having read around the material online, it seems a decent set of wheels give the best performance increase per pound spent.

So the question is what wheelset should I invest in?

You can get models that claim to be Aero that range from a hundred pounds up to the low thousands. What would you recommend for a commuter?

A related but more searching question: would I even notice the difference at my level of performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over a 40-minute ride, you may not notice much.

One [older reference](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/rinard/aero/aerodynamics.htm) compares a then-standard 32-spoke 27" wheel to an aero rim with 28 bladed spokes, a high-end hub and an extra-lightweight tire. The estimated improvement over a one-hour time trial at 23mph was 44 seconds - an impressive improvement for racing, but not particularly meaningful for a commute. [A more recent comparison by Rolf](http://www.rolfprima.com/techinfo_aero_results.php) to the aerodynamic Mavic Ksyrium claims that their $2500 TT85 full-carbon disc wheelset saves 1 minute, 49 seconds over 40km.

Comment: This. Your commute time is 39 minutes, and to shave even 5 minutes off that would require going nearly 3mph faster. That's going to come from stronger legs, higher endurance, and perhaps from choosing routes with fewer traffic lights. Not $1,500 wheels. Not to mention, any expensive wheels will simply become an easy target for theft, and be much more likely to get damaged. Neither of those are qualities you're looking for when you're commuting.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking two questions here:

1. As answered above, aero wheels aren't likely to improve your speed enough to be worth the investment, unless you also use the bike for club racing, triathlons, or the like.
2. Good wheels come in 2 categories:

   - Aero: An aero wheel's main benefit is in improving the shape of the foil around your  bike. Good aero wheels save approximate 30 seconds to one minute off of a ride, if you are above 22mph. Examples include Zipp 404/808/1080 series wheels. The Xentis Squad 5.8 carbon clincher wheels are among the lightest, strongest, and most aero wheels, with the additional benefit that the braking surface is designed for a standard rubber brake pad, so no buying special carbon rubber compound or cork pads.
   - Light: If your purpose is to get your speed up, depending on the conditions of your commute, you may be better served to do a light weight climbing oriented wheel. The reason that wheels are considered your best upgrade to just about any bike, is because losing a pound at the rim of your wheel has a similar effect to losing a much greater weight at the core of the bike. Put a weight on the end of a pole, and try to pick it up. Then drop the pole, and go pick it up directly. It will be much heavier at the end of a lever, and the longer the lever, the heavier it gets. Your wheels are weight that must be moved at the end of a 190mm lever, and maintained at speed there. At the least, a lighter wheel will make your bike feel and respond faster, and more nimbly. Even if you don't gain significant speed, in this way there are other benefits. Here also I recommend the Xentis Squad 2.5. A low profile carbon climbing wheel, light strong and fast. May or may not be available in the US, however.
   - There is a trade off for the everyday user between height of the sidewall for aero effect, and the side wind profile for handling and stability.
   - Finally, good wheels aren't cheap, and you should be prepared to spend in some cases as much as the bike cost originally. They are an upgrade that can and will outlast several bikes. My current wheels have been on 4 different road bikes, so don't consider them an add-on to the value of the bike. And don't get rid of the original wheels, you may need them when it's time to upgrade the other half of the bike.

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Aren't wheels a consumable item? Or can braking surfaces be replaced?

Comment: Wheels that are improperly cared for can be consumables. But when you're talking about wheels that are equal in cost to a decent bicycle, no. It becomes cost effective to repair, rather than replace a wheel set. A Zipp Firecrest 808 Carbon Clincher set in our area sells for about 11500 dirhams, depending on Euro exchange rates. I can buy a replacement rim, and have it installed for about 2500. Also, although I'm getting close to needing to replace the rear rim on my wheels, I've yet to have to do so. If the wheels were 500, and the rim was 200, plus 450 labor, that would be a consumable wheel.

Comment: Your number 2 bullet is boooogus.  Any decent wheel is balanced such that the weight of the "going up" side is exactly offset by the weight of the "going down" side.  It's like banging on the side of a truck full of canaries -- the truck isn't going to get any lighter.  However, there would be a very slight (but also very cheap) advantage to exactly balancing the wheel by placing a small weight opposite the stem.  But again the advantage would be maybe a fraction of a second in 40km.  Reducing weight overall on the bike is probably the best thing for climbing (other than stronger legs).

Comment: It turns out that the math for the total effect of lighter wheels vs lighter frame components shows that is [actually a quite minuscule effect](http://pardo.net/bike/pic/fail-027/index.html). Aerodynamic effects are significantly larger. It's also worth remembering that a gram off the rider is the same as a gram off the bike, but probably cheaper.

Comment: What is your background exactly? Where do you get your information, and how? I understand your idea about the wheels, balance definitely plays a part. but it's rotating a mass, not lifting one. All of it is moving in one direction: forward. The effect balance has is non-existent unless it isn't there.

Comment: @Lantius: I ddon't understand the math at the link you posted well enough to comment. But useful aero effects are limited to speeds typically above 22 mph. That means in the case described above that the aero benefit would be smaller than a weight benefit. I wasn't intending to say that weight on the frame is unimportant. Just that the wheel weight would likely be more important in this case. Please feel free to explain the math in smalle bites, if it invalidates that in some way.

Comment: @zenbike Basically, wheel weight only counts "more" when you are accelerating. Once it's moving, it doesn't take more energy to keep a large mass turning than a small mass - only the friction from the bearings and in the tire-road interface come into play. A decent estimate of effort at 20kph (12mph) on flat land is [20W](http://www.exploratorium.edu/cycling/aerodynamics1.html), or about 72kJ of energy for an hour's ride. At 20kph, the total energy of a rotating 2kg weight is 0.25*(2kg)*(20kph)^2 = 15J. Even if you full-stopped every minute it'd still be about 1% of the total energy spent.

Comment: @zenbike Of course, a fraction of a percent over the course of something like the Tour de France is a big deal; the margins are that slim between the top contenders in the sport and tiny percentages add up over the many days of racing. But for the average person, it's not that significant.

Comment: People, please shut it down or take it to chat.

Comment: @Lantus: I agree with all of that. It's part of why I said it may make sense depending on conditions of the ride. One question: when you are climbing, you are accelerating, being slowed by gravity, and accelerating again with each pedal stroke. In my understanding, that is why a lighter rim area of the wheel produces disproportionate effects, at least in terms of how the bike feels and handles?